# How to customize horizontal lines position in Recharts CartesianGrid?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying out Recharts on ReactJS recently and I am having problem to customise the position of the horizontal line of `CartesianGrid`.

This is what I got at first: [Before positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxSwK.png)

This is what I would like to achieve: [After positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAd0k.png)

I would like to make the bars sit between the grids. So what I have done here is to change the styling with css.

```
.recharts-cartesian-grid-horizontal line:nth-last-child(n+3) {
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
}
```

But the problem with this is that the lines alignments might be off when the size of the charts changed. I am wondering how can I do this in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After so many days, I found that this could be done with `horizontalPoints` prop on `CartesianGrid`. I can readjust the horizontal grid line by providing an array of points to the prop.

Comment: How did the array look like?